Django Admin TabularInline: How do I hide the object name of a M2M through model?
How do I hide Unit_attribute object (3) from the admin display?

admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin

from core.models import Attribute, Unit

class UnitAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Unit.attributes.through

@admin.register(Unit)
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UnitAttributeInline]

models.py:
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Unit(models.Model):
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)


You can easily change something like that with css. Inline write:
class UnitAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):

    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ["my_styles.css"],
        }

and in my_styles.css:
fieldset .inline_label{
    display: none;
}

Hiding something in Admin css is the quickest and most painless way. Because you don't need to write tests for that :)
p.s. Please check your own css_class, because it may change a bit in different versions of django in the admin templates.
For example it can be:
fieldset .origin { } # new versions of django

fieldset .original { } # very old versions of django

